# Python3: Index out of range for script that worked before

Tags: python-3.x

the attached script returns:

> IndexError: list index out of range

for the line starting with values = {line.split (...)

```
values=dict()
with open(csv) as f:
    lines =f.readlines()
    values = {line.split(',')[0].strip():line.split(',')[1].strip() for line in lines}
```

However, I could use it yesterday for doing exactly the same: 
replacing certain text in a dir of xml-files with different texts

```
import os
    from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

    drc = 'D:/Spielwiese/00100_Arbeitsverzeichnis'
    backup = 'D:/Spielwiese/Backup/'
    csv = 'D:/persons1.csv' 

    copy_tree(drc, backup)

    values=dict()
    with open(csv) as f:
        lines =f.readlines()
        values = {line.split(',')[0].strip():line.split(',')[1].strip() for line in lines}

    #Getting a list of the full paths of files 
    for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk(drc):
        for fname in filename:
            #Joining dirpath and filenames 
            path = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
            #Opening the files for reading only
            filedata = open(path,encoding="Latin-1").read() 
            for k,v in values.items():
               filedata=filedata.replace(k,v)
               f = open(path, 'w',encoding="Latin-1")
            # We are writing the the changes to the files   
               f.write(filedata) 
               f.close() #Closing the files

    print("In case something went wrong, you can find a backup in " + backup)
```

I don't see anything weird and I could, as mentioned before use it before ... :-o 
Any ideas on how to fix it?

best Wishes, 
K

Comment: Check if you have blank lines in the csv file.

Comment: When I change the name persons1.csv to persons.csv it works again - any hints? (The name is not important to me, but I'd love to know :-D )

Comment: That's weird, check if you're still reading the same file. Also check if you have to escape the backslashes.

Comment: The only thing I changed is the 1 at the end of it ... I did not even copy the file but literally rename it ... :-D 
the backslashes ? :-D I thought Python needed those ? 
normally I get  C:/path/to/file/ (am on Win10)

Comment: very weird: I just checked another file-name for the csv and this neither does work!